# How to create mkfs for LFS?

Tags: filesystems, windows-subsystem-for-linux, alpine-linux, lfs, mkfs

I am trying to run following command `mkfs -v -t ext4 /dev/sda1` to create file system but I got an output `/dev/sda1 is apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here!`. How can I create an file sytem and prevent this error. I alredy created partitions. I am using Alpine Linux distro on WSL.

Comment: why do you think you need to make a file system? anyway, it's exactly as the error says, the program you need isn't installed. Use you Linux distro's methods to install it.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I need it to create root file system. It is in official Linux from scratch guide.

Comment: @MarcusMüller  Ok. I got that program by typing `apk add e2fsprogs` but now it gave me an output `/dev/sda1 is apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here!` do you have any idea how can I make file system there now please?

Comment: A few questions - (a) are you using Windows 11 or an Insider/Dev build of Windows 10?  You will have to in order to make other drives available to WSL.  (b) If so, what type of drive are you using for this?  What process did you use to set it up?

Comment: Nobody here knows what your `/dev/sda1` is or whether creating a filesystem on it is the correct thing to do, or why your system tells you it's already in use.  Also, what's the relevance of LFS to this?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Windows 10 Home. I am using C drive type of SSD. There wasn'´t any proces mentoied to do I jus created parttions one for Linux Swap of size 1GB and other Linux if size 30GB.

Comment: @they Sorry for not being clear. It´s path on disk where I created my Linux Swap / Solaris of size 1GB. I got it like this `Device     Boot   Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sda1          2048  2099199  2097152   1G 82 Linux swap / Solaris `  
 `/dev/sda2       2099200 65013759 62914560  30G 83 Linux`

Comment: @Leviathan As you can see, attempting to format multi-line output in comments is pretty much unreadable.  You should edit any new information into your question.  Thanks!

Comment: @Leviathan So `sda1` is swap. Then it should clearly not have a filesystem.

Comment: @they so I don't have to create it then and continuing in next steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to face a number of issues attempting to do an LFS using WSL, but the first and main one at the moment is that, with WSL (both version 1 and 2) on Windows 10, there is *no* access to any drive other than the virtual ones that WSL creates for you.

Since you are attempting to `mkfs` on the existing virtual drive that WSL provides, yes, it is in use already by WSL.  You can't `mkfs` on a drive that's in-use, regardless of whether it is physical or virtual.

Also, since WSL2 is a virtualized environment, you do not have any *direct* access to physical hardware, including drives.  Windows 11 changes this somewhat by allowing you access both to physical drives, as well as the ability to create new virtual ones.

It *might* be possible to do LFS using Windows 11, but even there I can't make any guarantees.  The directions for doing so will certainly not be the same as the LFS doc provides, and you will need a mid-to-advanced level understanding of WSL and Linux in order to adjust the directions to work on WSL.

Comment: So what should I try to do? Shoul I create partitions on sdb instead ? My sdb disk is empty.

Comment: @Leviathan No.  Again, you will *not* be able to do this on Windows 10.  You have no access to the actual drive hardware, and the only virtual drives you will have access to are in-use by WSL.

Comment: If i don't want to upgrade to Windows 11 are there any alternatives? What about using VirtualBox?

Comment: @Leviathan Sure, lots of people seem to use LFS in VirtualBox.

Comment: Thanks for answer man! So I'll use VirtualBox then :)